# How do I insert rows and move the rest down based on a sort order number?

Tags: sql, sorting, move

How can I create a procedure that inserts a record into a table by a sort order (ranking column) and moves the rest down. For example, my sp receives the input of `PhysID(FK)`, `UserID(FK)`, `UserRoleID(FK)`, which have a constraint that they must be a unique combination, and the last input, `SortOrder` which determines where the combination is inserted within the table and every record after that sort order moves down (or adds 1 to the sort order) to make room for the inserted row.

There are three `roleid` options per `physid`. Each `userid` is allowed to fill any of the 3 roles but not more than one per `physid`. Each `roleid` has backup `userid`s per `physid`. Once a `userid` has been used for any role under a certain physid, that `userid` is no longer a candidate for selection.

After that's accomplished, how can I insert records according to a sort order number that updates all the records with an equal or higher sort order by adding 1, therefore moving them down in the sort order.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_InsertRole 
    @PhysID int,
    @UserID int,
    @UserRoleID tinyint,
    @SortOrder int
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN   
        UPDATE dbo.Physicians_Users
        SET SortOrder = SortOrder + 1
        WHERE @PhysID = PhysicianID AND UserRoleID = @UserRoleID AND @SortOrder >= @SortOrder
    END
    BEGIN
        SELECT @UserID = UserID FROM dbo.Users 
        IF not exists(SELECT UserID FROM dbo.Physicians_User WHERE PhysiciansID = @PhysID AND @UserID = UserID)
        INSERT INTO dbo.Physicians_Users(PhysicianID,UserID,UserRoleID,SortOrder)
        VALUES(@PhysID,@UserID,@UserRoleID,@SortOrder)
    END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @@ERROR
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH

RETURN 0 

GO
```

Comment: At the end of the WHERE clause, it seems SortOrder was cut off when pasting.

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_InsertRole 
@PhysID int,
@UserID int,
@UserRoleID tinyint,
@SortOrder int
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  BEGIN TRY                    
    IF NOT EXISTS(
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.Physicians_User
                  WHERE PhysiciansID = @PhysID AND UserRoleID = @UserRoleID
                    AND UserID = @UserID
                  )
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO dbo.Physicians_Users(PhysicianID, UserID, UserRoleID, SortOrder)
      VALUES (@PhysID, @UserID, @UserRoleID, @SortOrder)

      UPDATE dbo.Physicians_Users
      SET SortOrder = SortOrder + 1
      WHERE @PhysID = PhysicianID AND UserRoleID = @UserRoleID
        AND SortOrder >= @SortOrder
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  SELECT @@ERROR
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH

RETURN 0 

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these versions of the query.  I think you are confusing the scalar arguments to the function with the column names:

```
BEGIN   
    UPDATE dbo.Physicians_Users
        SET SortOrder = SortOrder + 1
        WHERE @PhysID = PhysicianID AND UserRoleID = @UserRoleID AND
              SortOrder >= @SortOrder;   -- <-- this is the line that changed
END
BEGIN
    SELECT @UserID = UserID FROM dbo.Users;
    IF not exists(SELECT UserID
                  FROM dbo.Physicians_User
                  WHERE PhysiciansID = @PhysID AND @UserID = UserID)
    INSERT INTO dbo.Physicians_Users(PhysicianID,UserID,UserRoleID,SortOrder)
        VALUES(@PhysID,@UserID,@UserRoleID,@SortOrder)
END
```

That fixes the syntax.  You can also express the `insert` without the `if` by doing:

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.Physicians_Users(PhysicianID,UserID,UserRoleID,SortOrder)
        select @PhysID, @UserID, @UserRoleID, @SortOrder
        where not exists(SELECT UserID
                  FROM dbo.Physicians_User
                  WHERE PhysiciansID = @PhysID AND @UserID = UserID)
```

The logic still isn't quite right.  If the record is already in the table, why update `sortorder`.  And, if the record is in the table, you should probably update the sort order for that record.